# How to invoke indication & notification as peripheral iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

What API call do I use to invoke either `indication` or `notification` if I setup iOS device as `peripheral`?

For instance lets say I setup characteristics with indication & notification properties like so:

```
    // Indication
    [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kIndicationUUID]
                                       properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite | CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate
                                            value:nil
                                      permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable | CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];

    // notification
    [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kNotificationUUID]
                                       properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify
                                            value:nil
                                      permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable | CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
```

When I update value of characteristic, how is implementation for sending indication different than that of notification? Currently I am implementing the following - regardless of property type.

```
    characteristic.value = self.request.value;
    [self.peripheralManager respondToRequest:self.request withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];
    BOOL didSendValue = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:self.request.value forCharacteristic:characteristic onSubscribedCentrals:@[]];
```

Comment: There is no difference, at a code level, between indication and notification. At the Bluetooth level indication requires a response from the central that it received the update.  Your code doesn't need to do anything differently

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, and even though that's out my control at code level, what method precedes this activity? calling `respondToRequest:withResult:` right?

Comment: No. A notify or indicate is sent when you call `updateValue`. You call `respondToRequest` when you have received a read or write request.